# Can't initialize ArrayListMultimap; due to nesting?

Tags: java, initialization

```
private ArrayListMultimap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Point2d>>> detectedAgentPositions;
```

The above code doesn't give me any errors, i.e everything is neatly written and imported etcetera. But when I try to initialize `detectedAgentPositions` like so:

```
private ArrayListMultimap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Point2d>>> detectedAgentPositions
        = new ArrayListMultimap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Point2d>>>();
```

I get the following error:

> no suitable constructor found for ArrayListMultimap(no arguments)
>       constructor ArrayListMultimap.ArrayListMultimap(int,int) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       constructor ArrayListMultimap.ArrayListMultimap(Multimap< ? extends Integer,? extends ArrayList>>) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

What is the problem here?

Comment: from where are `ArrayListMultiMap` and `Point2d`??

Comment: use `ArrayListMultimap.create` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class `ArrayListMultimap` is from **Google Common**, it doesn't work simply because the constructor is **private** such that you cannot call `new ArrayListMultimap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Point2d>>>()` directly simply call [`ArrayListMultimap.create()`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/11.0.1/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#create()) instead as next:

```
private ArrayListMultimap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Point2d>>> detectedAgentPositions 
    = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use interfaces, look the following code:

```
Multimap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Point2d>>> detectedAgentPositions = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Read here https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html